# Navigation bar image should change when the user logs in(JSF 2.0 + primefaces)

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I use a primefaces dock as a nav bar. I want it to change one of its images depending on if the user is logged in or not. I did something but it doesn't work, because i see the two icons at the same time and also i cant click the logout button. Can you give me some advice?

This is the nav bar(It is created in a template all pages use):

```
<h:body>
        <h:form>
        <p:dock position="top">
            <p:menuitem value="Naslovna" icon="unsecuredimages/naslovna.png"
                url="main.xhtml" alt="The image could not be found." />
            <p:menuitem value="Register" icon="unsecuredimages/register.png"
                url="registration.xhtml" alt="The image could not be found." />
            <p:menuitem value="Cesta pitanja" icon="unsecuredimages/faq.png"
                url="faq.xhtml" alt="The image could not be found." />

            <p:menuitem value="Login" icon="unsecuredimages/login.png" url="login.xhtml" rendered ="securityController.checkLogged() == false"/>
        <p:menuitem value="Logout" icon="unsecuredimages/logout.png" action="securityController.logOut()" rendered ="securityController.checkLogged() == true"/>

        </p:dock>   
        </h:form>
```

This is how the securityController Backing bean looks like:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SecurityController {

    @EJB
    private IAuthentificationEJB authentificationEJB;

    ...

    public boolean checkLogged() {
        return authentificationEJB.checkAuthentificationStatus();
    }

    ...
}
```

In the process there is also an EJB involved:

```
@Stateful(name = "ejbs/AuthentificationEJB")
public class AuthentificationEJB implements IAuthentificationEJB {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

        ....

        // Check if user is logged in
    public boolean checkAuthentificationStatus() {
        // 1-Check if there is something saved in the session(This means the
        // user is logged in)
        if ((FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getSessionMap().get("userRole") != null)) {
            // 2-If there is not a user already loged, then return false
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

        ...
```

What do you think how can i add this feature to my nav bar?

**Update**

```
<p:menuitem value="Login" icon="unsecuredimages/login.png" url="login.xhtml" rendered ="securityController.checkLogged"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Logout" icon="unsecuredimages/logout.png" action="securityController.logOut()" rendered ="!securityController.checkLogged"/>
```

i also changed to:

```
public boolean isCheckLogged() {
        return authentificationEJB.checkAuthentificationStatus();
    }
```

This is how the navigation looks like. As you see i don't see login or logout icons.

[image]

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `c:if` use the `rendered` attribute of `p:menuitem` (or any other primefaces component).

Like this:

```
<p:menuitem value="Login" icon="unsecuredimages/login.png" url="login.xhtml" rendered="#{securityController.checkLogged}"/>
<p:menuitem value="Logout" icon="unsecuredimages/logout.png" action="securityController.logOut()" rendered="#{!securityController.checkLogged}"/>
```

You will need a `getCheckLogged()` or `isCheckLogged()` method in your securityController bean. So:

```
public boolean getCheckLogged() {
    return authentificationEJB.checkAuthentificationStatus();
}
```

EL will translate the `securityController.checkLogged` attribute reference to a getter method call by naming convention.

Comment: I did exactly as you said. See the update above. Now i don't see any icon. Why is that?

Comment: Check it again. Instead of "rendered ="securityController.checkLogged() == false" you MUST useit like rendered="#{securityController.checkLogged}". Did you try this? Also the method MUST start with "get" or "is". Details are important.

Comment: Yes i did exactly like that see the update where it says Update not the original question. I am afraid the error could be in the EJB. What do you think?

Comment: I still cannot see #{} in your rendered attribute... If the bean was faulty then it would show exactly one line, depending on whether it returns true or false. If you see both menuitems or none, then the problem is in your JSF page (or backing bean)...

Comment: Can you see my update? I just posted a printscreen that shows the nav bar. Just in case here i paste the code i use:

`<p:menuitem value="Login" icon="unsecuredimages/login.png" url="login.xhtml" rendered ="securityController.checkLogged"/>
   <p:menuitem value="Logout" icon="unsecuredimages/logout.png" action="securityController.logOut()" rendered ="!securityController.checkLogged"/>`

Comment: I still don't see #{securityController.checkLogged}. Note the #{} characters! These tell JSF that this is an EL expression that must be evaluated.

Comment: My apologies please i was forgetting the brackets all the the time :) It works fine. I see the icon changing when i log in. 
Thank you!